# How to implement TimePicker correctly

Tags: android, timepicker

I've got an app that needs to show a TimePicker dialog. I can get the TimePicker to show on the app but there seems to throw an NPE when I try to attach the Listener. Is this implemented correctly?

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(NfcscannerActivity.this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialogboxmanuallogout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NfcscannerActivity.this);

// set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

//final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
//.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);
tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(timeChangedListener);

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                //Log.e(TAG, "about to get the hour from tp");
                //Integer hour = new Integer(1);
                //int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                //Log.e(TAG, "just got the hour from tp");
                //Integer minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();

                Toast.makeText(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                    "Last logout has been updated at "+ tp.getCurrentHour() + tp.getCurrentMinute() ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();



private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener timeChangedListener = new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, "time changed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
};
```

[update1]

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please enter time of last logout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />





    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timepicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />







</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the view from the content View of the activity rather than Dialog.

So after `alertDialogBuilder.create();` use below code

```
final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);
tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(timeChangedListener);
```

Comment: hi, no there is still a NPE at tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(timeChangedListener);

Comment: did you remove the first call? and if you have removed the first call then post the layout xml dialogboxmanuallogout

Comment: can you edit your original code too, after making above changes?

Comment: i've tested tp for null and it is null.

Comment: hey that worked! thanks alot! timepicker1 is part of promptsview. thanks again!

Comment: having a problem using the + or - button having that NPE inputstate

Comment: can you post the exception stack